# Вывод текста из txt в JTextArea

Tags: java, textarea, файлы, swing

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом сделать так, чтобы пользователь выбирал файл в JFileChooser и после этого содержимое выбранного txt файла выводилось в JTextArea??

У меня только 1 вариант, и тот не работает:

```
class OpenFile implements ActionListener{

    JFileChooser cf;
    int ret;
    File q;
    String line;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            cf = new JFileChooser();
            ret = cf.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                q=cf.getCurrentDirectory();
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(q));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) lists.get(tp.getSelectedIndex()).append(line);

            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q = cf.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: @woesss, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.